# Add images to a div by removing old images at runtime

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a slider what displays more than 80 images taken from database in a vertical scroll

Here is the code at runtime

```
<div class="albums-div">
        <ul class="slides" style="width:148px; height:148px">

            <?php

                  foreach($rings as $ring)
                  {
                    echo '<li> <input class="teringimage"  type="image" src="'. $ring['ringThumbNailImagePath'] .'" name="checked" value="' . $ring['id'].'" data-my-info="'. $ring['ringSetName'] .'" style="width:143px; height:143px;"></li>';
                  }            
             ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

At some point, i want to do the query again. The purpose is to remove all the images and then replace with new images inside.

Following is the code

```
 jQuery('#albums-div ul.slides').empty();
                            jQuery.each( msg.data, function( i, val ) 
                            {
                                jQuery('#albums-div ul.slides').append('<li> <input class="teringimage"  type="image" src="'+val['ringThumbNailImagePath']+'" name="checked" value="' + val['id']+'" data-my-info="'+val['ringSetName'] +'"  width="150" height="150"></li>');
                            });
```

Now msg.data is an array taken from db. it is not empty but neither the images are removed nor new are added.

Any ideas

Comment: Please check it again
 
where is img tag

Comment: In your jquery selector you use `#` for `albums-div`, instead use a `.`

Comment: @RobinvdA cmon... what a stupid mistake. thanks... make an answer and i accept it

Comment: @RobinvdA just one more thing. Now i can't make the click work on them jQuery('.teringimage').click(function(){ is not getting called

Comment: As you are adding content dynamically, use `on`, try this for click `$('.albums-div ul.slides').on('click', '.teringimage', function() {`

Comment: @ManojYadav i do not want to put the click on slides, instead on teringimage which is already added but i think the class is not being properly added dynamically why

Comment: click handler is for `'.teringimage'` and not for `slides`, `slides` is used to `delegate events`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jQuery selector use `.` (used for classes) instead of `#` (used for id's)

In answer to your comment:
Make sure to use `.on` when binding events to an element which is added dynamically.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DGs79/1/)

In your case (as Manoj Yadav noted):

```
$('.albums-div ul.slides').on('click', '.teringimage', function() {

});
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)